# How to decrypt LDAP passwords Hashed as MD5?

Tags: hash, encoding

I am doing a penetration test, and i would like to know if i can decrypt passwords stored in LDAP. i tried some sites decrypt MD5 , they give me error message tells that the input is not MD5.
Could you please help 
thanks

This is an example

```
userPassword: {MD5}KdScezWFVZxY7rHb5C4X1w==
```

Comment: Hashing is not encryption.  You cannot decrypt an MD5; you can only find a collision.

Comment: And LDAP is not a storage location, it's a communications protocol.

Comment: ok, i got the tree stored in LDAP and it contains passwords hashed using MD5, but when i am trying sites to get the original pass, the site gives error message tells "the input is not MD5". i wish it is more clear now.

Comment: MD5 is not a difficult "format": it is 16 bytes of pure, raw data (or 32 ASCII-formatted hexadecimal numbers in the range of [0-9a-fA-F]). Anything else is not a valid MD5 signature.

Comment: @user1028: could you post one of the hashes you've got, just to verify if it's a valid md5 hash ?

Comment: Based on the appending == it looks like it is encoded and not only encrypted. Decoding it with base64 does not provide a valid md5 string.

Comment: @Karrax - I'm getting a valid MD5 (32 bit ascii-hexidecimal) from decoding.  See my answer.

Comment: wierd @drjimbob ..My Burpsuite pro edition gives the following base64 decode: )Ô{5UXî±Ûä.×

Comment: @drjimbob , online base64 decoder gives me: S2RTY2V6V0ZWWnhZN3JIYjVDNFgxdz09 which looks more correct.

Comment: Other than references in WAHH, not familiar with burpsuite.  It seems like burp is assuming some weird encoding for the b64 decode; rather than re-encoding in hexidecimal.  A 24 char b64 encoding ending with `==` should be 16 bytes (each set of four-b64 chars corresponds to 3 bytes; except the last with has only one indicated by the two equals).  As a byte is two hex chars, this works out right.

Answer (score 11):

Your MD5 hash `{MD5}KdScezWFVZxY7rHb5C4X1w==` appears to be base64 encoded.  MD5 hashes in the rainbow tables probably would be in hexidecimal, so you should convert the two.

In python you can do this with

```
>>> from base64 import b64decode, b16encode
>>> b16encode(b64decode('KdScezWFVZxY7rHb5C4X1w==')).lower()
'29d49c7b3585559c58eeb1dbe42e17d7'
```

Or you can use: http://tomeko.net/online_tools/base64.php?lang=en

Answer (score 2):

In order to try and identify the password that gives you a particular hash, the only real way is to try all passwords and hash them to see what you get.

What those websites have done is already tried a huge number of passwords and stored the calculated hashes so when you input your hash they quickly look up their database and provide you with an answer. Have a look at [this question on Rainbow Tables.](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/379/485)

They do not cope with salted hashes, however (well, you can create a table for each salt, but that dramatically increases the size of the table space) - so the answer you have had back may just mean they have failed to look up that hash.

Answer (score 1):

John The Ripper knows how to deal with the LDAP hashes.  The option `-format=nsldap` should force it.

If it doesn't recognize your format, use `base64.exe -d b64enc.hash | xxd -ps` to convert your base64 encoded hashes into a hexdump.

Answer (score 0):

dr jimbob right, it seems to be base64 encoded.

you can try http://md5pass.com to find your hash password. that site does not use a very own database but a Google Custom Search Engine (CSE).