# Estimating the size of a rainbow table

Tags: cryptography, passwords, hash, cryptanalysis

[What are rainbow tables and how are they used?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/379/what-are-rainbow-tables-and-how-are-they-used) Gives a very precise answer about what rainbow tables are and how they are used. I had always confused hash-tables and rainbow tables. My question is regarding the size of the rainbow tables. Now, for a hash table, the size of the file would be :

let `n = ( size of the input plain text file )` (Assuming one line per plain-text)

so `size(hash table) = n + (bytes in hash)*h + n ( for separation) Bytes`

On the other hand, is there a similar mechanism to estimate the size of a rainbow table ? I am sure there is, since tools used to generate a rainbow table usually have a size estimate on them.

How is the size of a rainbow table estimated, given:

charset, chain length, min and max length of plain text.

This would give a better understanding of how and why rainbow tables are better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[RainbowCrack](http://project-rainbowcrack.com/) is probably what you would be using to generate rainbow tables.  Rainbow tables are **always** generated over a keyspace,  such as alpha-numeric 5-9 bytes long and the chain length and count which will affect the rate and the size of the resulting tables.  If you have an input file,  then it's not a rainbow table,  it's some other lookup table.   A rainbow table is a speical type of lookup table with neat properties.  Such as the size of the hash function (`sha256` vs `sha512`) doesn't affect the size of the rainbow table.

There are some matlab scripts floating around to calculate the size of rainbow table,  however [this site is easier to use](http://www.tobtu.com/rtcalc.php).

Comment: Cool calculator. 
Note that rainbow tables are much trickier beasts compared to simple hash tables. For example, rainbow tables are probabilistic and can never ensure 100% coverage of the full key space (which is why the calculator contains a "total success rate" parameter). It's possible to increase the success rate for a given size table (by increasing the number of tables), but this increases the time it takes to search for a specific hash within the table. For details, read Oechslin's classic paper on rainbow tables [(PDF)](http://lasec.epfl.ch/pub/lasec/doc/Oech03.pdf).

Comment: @David Wachtfogel  good point.

Comment: From my understanding, the rainbow table contains 2 columns, 1.plaintext(starting seed) 2.Hash(final hash). The plain text size depends on the charset that we had given initially and I assume it varies in length from 5-8 or whatever we specify. I don't understand why you say that type of Hash doesnt play a role in the size. size(SHA512) > size(SHA256) => size(2nd column) would increase. Correct ?

Comment: @asudhak nope,  that is a lookup table,  not a rainbowtable.

Answer (score 4):

A rainbow table is characterized by its *average chain length*. It is a parameter which is chosen at table construction time. Let's call it *t*.

If the table covers about *N* tentative passwords, then it will have a size of about *N/t* "entries", where an entry is a "chain end". The encoded size of a chain end depends on a lot of details, but it will typically be as large, or somewhat larger, than a field which can hold the integer value *N*. In other words, if *N* is close to 2<sup>40</sup>, each entry will need at least 5 bytes, but probably a bit more than that, say 8 bytes.

To save on storage cost, you will want to make *t* as big as possible. However, you cannot make it as big as you want, because it raises other costs. Briefly stated:

- The **table construction cost** is about *1.7*N* evaluations of the hash function.
- The **storage cost** is *N/t* chain ends.
- The **CPU cost** when attacking is about *t<sup>2</sup>* evaluations of the hash function.
- The **lookup cost** when attacking is about *t* random accesses in the tables.

A modern hard disk allows about 100 lookups per second, so if you want to keep attack time below one minute, you cannot have *t* higher than 6000. You can have much higher values for *t* if you use SSD (which allow for many thousands of random accesses per second), but storage cost increases because SSD are quite expensive. Also, if *t* becomes too high, the quadratic CPU cost can become prohibitive.

The difference between a *rainbow* table, what existed before (Hellman's time-memory trade-off), and the modern variants which mix ideas from Hellman, Oechslin, Rivest, Biham and a few others, is a factor of at most 2 in CPU and lookup costs.