# Is encrypting something more than once safer than hashing more than once?

Tags: encryption, hash, keepass

I am aware of the implications that **hashing** something more than once correctly will increase the security of a system, but doing it incorrectly will decrease it, as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/348140/2416394) and on various other sources.

But I stumbled upon a feature of Keepass, where the password database is encrypted N times to increase the work factor for brute force or dictionary attacks. This part explains how it is done: [Protection against Dictionary Attacks](http://keepass.info/help/base/security.html#secdictprotect)

While I think that I am aware of the implication of hashing several times I am unsure whether encrypting several times, as explained above, increases robustness of the database.

Disclaimer: I've read [Keepass Dictionary Attack Protection Strategy](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56220/keepass-dictionary-attack-protection-strategy)

Comment: Related: [Is multiple encryption a good idea?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18087/is-multiple-encryption-a-good-idea)

Comment: Similar: [Is it safer to encrypt twice with RSA?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5382/is-it-safer-to-encrypt-twice-with-rsa)

Comment: You may want to re-read the first link. The *very first* sentence states that hashing multiple times is essential to the security of password hashing schemes.

Comment: I think you miss read the link about hashing multiple time. Hashing multiple times actually increase your password strength because it takes longer to brute force it. But you have to do it right, so use a library for that.

Comment: @Krumia, regarding your second link, while I understand that encrypting twice might be trivial but when computation power increases in a way where a brute force or dictionary attack can be done in a reasonable time frame adding a work factor of a large value (for current systems) to slow down computation would still affect the overall time, right? Of course only when the work factor is large enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a different scheme. Generally it is accepted that when using a password hashing algorithm, which is intended to be very slow, is acceptable. What KeePass is doing is very similar to what most hashing algorithms do, namely slowing down hash calculation.

Their way is not a standard way. Most password hashing algorithms, such as PBKDF2, scrypt and bcrypt can actually also be tuned in the number of rounds to be used as to increase workload.

The question about which is more secure has to be put into perspective. If you slow down the hashing as much as with their encryption scheme, then the security should be the same.