# Given a hash, salt, charset and password length, how do you get the password without brute-forcing it?

Tags: encryption, passwords, brute-force

I got that question on an exercise and I'm not sure what to answer.

Without conventional brute-forcing and without a rainbow table, how could I find out the password?

An improved brute-force algorithm is acceptable, but how could I improve it?

Comment: Using a dictionary or the GNU Magic Tool (tm).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a decent hash function, **the only way to find the password in this situation is to guess it**. This is true for any [cryptographic hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function): it's the meaning of the preimage resistance property. This is true for any cryptographic hash; password hash functions have additional properties ([salt and slowness](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords)) that make it more expensive to verify guesses.

[Rainbow tables](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/379/what-are-rainbow-tables-and-how-are-they-used) work by precomputing the hash of many passwords and storing them in a way that allows quickly finding the password from the hash if the password is in the precomputed set. In other words, you make a lot of guesses in advance.

“Conventional brute-forcing” is an ambiguous term. It may refer to trying passwords in a naive order (e.g. by increasing length). But you're free to make guesses in any order. For example, it makes sense to try [`123456`, `password` and `iloveyou`](http://www.cbsnews.com/news/the-25-most-common-passwords-of-2013/) before `quszoy` and `nyoktw`. So make sure that you try guesses [in an](http://blog.erratasec.com/2012/06/linkedin-vs-password-cracking.html) [intelligent](http://arstechnica.com/security/2013/05/how-crackers-make-minced-meat-out-of-your-passwords/) [order](http://arstechnica.com/security/2013/08/thereisnofatebutwhatwemake-turbo-charged-cracking-comes-to-long-passwords/).

You cannot find the password in any other way by computational means, but you may be able to find it by **external means**, such as:

- Snooping: wait until the user enters their password and watch over their shoulder, listen to their keystrokes, …
- Spyware: plant a keylogger (physical or software) on the user's computer and wait until they enter their password.
- Data leak: read the post-it note on their monitor, or crack the bank safe and open the envelope.
- Man-in-the-middle: listen to the communication between the user's computer and the password-protected server while they're typing their password.
- Phishing: pretend to be the server system administrator or other authority figure and get the user to type their password on your computer instead of the legitimate one.
- Social engineering: offer the user a lot of money or a [bar of chocolate](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/technology/3639679.stm). If it fails, apply [wrench cryptanalysis](http://xkcd.com/538/) (or a [rubber hose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber-hose_cryptanalysis) if you're a stickler for tradition).